# Select from nested list and dropping non matching elements

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have the following nested list

```
{{{0.1,0.1, {{p->-4.01, g->0.93},{p->0.60, g->0.93}}},
 {0.1,0.2,  {{p->-4.54, g->0.93},{p->0.63, g->0.93}}}},
 {{0.2,0.1, {{p->-4.26, g->0.86},{p->1.62, g->0.86}}},
 {0.2,0.2,  {{p->4.91, g->0.84},{p->0.66, g->0.84}}}}}
```

(The true list is much longer). I would like to select the element of the list for which 0<= p <=1 and discard the other element of the sublist that contains a p>1 | p<0. This is what I want:

```
{{{0.1,0.1, {{p->0.60, g->0.93}}},
 {0.1,0.2,  {{p->0.63, g->0.93}}}},
 {0.2,0.2,  {{p->0.66, g->0.84}}}}}
```

This does almost what I want
    tbl = Select[tbl, #[[2]][[2]][[1]][[2]] > 0 && #[[2]][[2]][[1]][[2]] <= 1 &]; 
almost because it does not drop the non matching elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
list = {{{0.1, 0.1, {{p -> -4.01, g -> 0.93}, {p -> 0.60, g -> 0.93}}},
         {0.1, 0.2, {{p -> -4.54, g -> 0.93}, {p -> 0.63, g -> 0.93}}}},
        {{0.2, 0.1, {{p -> -4.26, g -> 0.86}, {p -> 1.62, g -> 0.86}}},
         {0.2, 0.2, {{p -> 4.91, g -> 0.84}, {p -> 0.66, g -> 0.84}}}}};

MapAt[DeleteCases[#, HoldPattern[{p -> pn_, g -> gn_}] /; ! (0 <= pn <= 1)] &, 
      list, {All, All, 3}]
   {{{0.1, 0.1, {{p -> 0.6, g -> 0.93}}},
     {0.1, 0.2, {{p -> 0.63, g -> 0.93}}}},
    {{0.2, 0.1, {}}, {0.2, 0.2, {{p -> 0.66, g -> 0.84}}}}}

DeleteCases[%, {_, _, {}}, {2}]
   {{{0.1, 0.1, {{p -> 0.6, g -> 0.93}}},
     {0.1, 0.2, {{p -> 0.63, g -> 0.93}}}},
    {{0.2, 0.2, {{p -> 0.66, g -> 0.84}}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may `Select` the items with `MapAt` at their location then `Query` the result to `Select` items from the first `Select` that are not empty.

```
Query[All, Select[Last@# != {} &]]@
 MapAt[Select[0 <= (p /. #) <= 1 &], {All, All, -1}]@list
```

> ```
> {{{0.1, 0.1, {{p -> 0.6, g -> 0.93}}}, 
>   {0.1, 0.2, {{p -> 0.63, g -> 0.93}}}}, 
>  {{0.2, 0.2, {{p -> 0.66, g -> 0.84}}}}}
> ```

Hope this helps.